# Array is shuffling in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display an array with 151 pokemons sorted by their pokedex positions (ex: 1 - bulbasaur, 2- ivysaur...), but every time I reload the page it brings me a different array, with the positions shuffled.

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Pokemon from './components/Pokemon';

const App = () => {
  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);

  const fetchPokemons = () => {
    for (let index = 1; index < 152; index += 1) {
      new Array(151).fill(
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index}`)
          .then((data) => data.json())
          .then((result) =>
            setPokemonData((prevState) => [...prevState, result])
          )
      );
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPokemons();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {pokemonData && <Pokemon data={pokemonData} />}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Pokemon.js:

```
const Pokemon = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      {data.map((pokemon) => (
        <div key={pokemon.name}>
          <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon.name} />
          <span>{pokemon.name}</span>
          <span>
            {pokemon.types.length >= 2
              ? `${pokemon.types[0].type.name}  ${pokemon.types[1].type.name}`
              : pokemon.types[0].type.name}
          </span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Pokemon;
```

Comment: Your current code is building a new array for each pokémon, and filling it with... well, undefined, eventually. The shuffling is due to the promises (of which you are currently making 151 of _in parallel_) resolving in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to guarantee the order, you'll need something like

```
  const fetchPokemons = async () => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let index = 1; index < 152; index += 1) {
      promises.push(fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index}`).then((data) => data.json()));
    }
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    setPokemonData(results);
  };
```

This will take a while as it loads all of the pokémon before showing any of them - if you don't want that, then there really are two options: rework things to do each request sequentially, or alternately switch to an array where some of the slots may be `null` while things are still being loaded (which will require changing your rendering code some too).

Comment: It is still possible to have race condition while awaiting all promises here await Promise.all(promises), it is not 100% that request that is fire first will finish first. To ensure that pokemons are sorted, it must eather wait for every call (which is slow), sort them after await Promise.all(promises); line, or get all pokemons at once from a single API call if there is backend api support for that. Please correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: @Wings `Promise.all()` only resolves once all of the promises in the array resolve, or when any of them rejects. There is no race condition here, only slowness.

Answer (score 1):

You are making 153 calls to api, which is not great I would highly recommend that you change into single api call to get all pokemons, to achieve this you can do it like this:

```
const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState<any>([]);

  const fetchPokemons = async () => {
      const data = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=153"`);
      const pokemons = await data.json();
      setPokemonData(pokemons.results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetchPokemons();
    })();
  }, []);
```

Also this will guarantee that you get data always in the same way. You will not face any race conditions and you won't any unnecessary api calls.